# Is it actually possible to use generics when defining mappings in Orika?

Tags: java, orika

I know about that type erasure and would prevent to use generics when defining mappings, as this question points out [how to map generics objects with Orika?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615401/how-to-map-generics-objects-with-orika). But [Orika FAQ](http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/faq.html), on the **Are generics supported** section, claims:

> Yes. Orika includes special runtime support for the mapping of generic types via a special Type class which can be used to define the exact type elements of a templated type.

Ideally something like the following should work (supposing we can somehow maintain the class parameters at runtime through some Orika functionality):

```
     mapperFactory.classMap(Asset<T,K>.class, AssetDto<K>.class)
    .maybeSomeCustomization...
    .byDefault()
    .register();
```

I was not able to find any example about the `Type<?>` class usage the Orika FAQ mentions.

Comment: Generic classes, e.g. `Asset<T,K>.class` don't exist, so you can't do it that way.

Comment: Yes, they don't, I would like to know about alternatives, like the Orika FAQ mentions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible, you need to use the `MapperFactory#classMap(Type<A>, Type<B>)` API instead of `MapperFactory#classMap(Class<A>, Class<B>)`.

You can find a lot of examples in Orika tests in the [`generics`](https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika/tree/master/tests/src/main/java/ma/glasnost/orika/test/generics) package.

To construct a `Type` instance you can use an in-place anonymous subclass of `TypeBuilder`:

```
Type<MyGenericClass<GenericParam1, GenericParam2>> type =
    new TypeBuilder<MyGenericClass<GenericParam1, GenericParam2>>() {}.build();
```

Note the brackets `{}` after the constructor which create the anonymous subclass. That way Orika can find out the actual `MyGenericClass<GenericParam1, GenericParam2>` type parameter using `((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, subclassing to find out the type arguments. The Orika FAQ could have actually pointed to the unit tests you mention.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TypeBuilder` API to retain the generic type information so that Orika can use it when performing the mapping.

Note that Java doesn't allow us to specify the type parameter in `Class` literals. For example, we can't write `Asset<Book>.class`. Furthermore, due to type erasure, we can't access the actual type parameter at runtime. In short raw types - i.e. `Asset.class` - don't provide enough information to Orika.

So firstly, we must create the generic types using `TypeBuilder`:

```
Type<Asset<Person>> sourceType = new TypeBuilder<Asset<Person>>() {}.build();
Type<AssetDto<Person>> targetType = new TypeBuilder<AssetDto<Person>>(){}.build();
```

Then in the `classMap` invocation, we must use these types:

```
factory.classMap(sourceType, targetType).byDefault().register();
```

Lastly, we can perform the mapping using these types:

```
factory.getMapperFacade().map(asset, sourceType, targetType);
```

Read the following post for a detailed explanation of [generics usage with Orika](http://www.javabyexamples.com/mapping-with-generics-using-orika).